# VBA Classes - How to have a class hold additional classes

Tags: vba, class

I have a challenge that I am trying to solve using classes.

I am logging transactions into a class.

Each transaction has the following:

- Name
- Date
- Time
- Description

However each transaction can also have many business related contacts with the following properties

- Business Contact Name
- Business Area
- Percentage of Bill

Are there any examples of how this would be done.

I have tried adding a second class for the business contact and then building a collection inside the transaction class, all with no joy.

I have also tried making the business contact details a collection within the transaction class also with no joy.

Below is what I have so far, but i may have gone down a blind alley and it may not be worth trying to rescue the code

Any help much appreciated.

Thanks
JP

---

### Test sub - trying to write the data in and get it back out

```
Sub test()

    Dim x As Integer
    Dim xx As Integer

    'code to populate some objects
    Dim clocklist As Collection
    Dim clock As classClocks
    Dim businesscontactlist As Collection
    Dim businesscontact As classBusinessContact

    Set businesscontactlist = New Collection
    Set clocklist = New Collection

    For x = 1 To 3
        Set clock = New classClocks
        clock.LawyerName = "lawyer " & Str(x)
        For xx = 1 To 3
            businesscontact.Name = "Business Contact " & Str(xx)
            businesscontactlist.Add businesscontact

        Next xx
        clock.BusinessContactAdd businesscontactlist '----- errors here
        clocklist.Add clock
    Next x

    Set businesscontactlist = Nothing

    'write the data backout again
    For Each clock In clocklist
        Debug.Print clock.LawyerName
        Set businesscontactlist = clock.BusinessContacts
        For Each businesscontact In businesscontactlist
            Debug.Print businesscontact.Name
        Next

    Next

End Sub
```

---

### Clock Class - this is the transaction class

```
Private pLawyerName As String
Private pBusinessContactList As Collection

Public Property Get LawyerName() As String
    LawyerName = pLawyerName
End Property

Public Property Let LawyerName(ByVal sLawyerName As String)
    pLawyerName = sLawyerName
End Property

Public Property Get BusinessContacts() As Collection
    Set BusinessContacts = pBusinessContactList
End Property

Public Property Set BusinessContactAdd(ByRef strName() As Collection)
    Set pBusinessContactList = New Collection
    Dim businesscontact As classBusinessContact
    Set businesscontact = New classBusinessContact

    For Each businesscontact In strName
        businesscontact.Name = strName.Item()
        pBusinessContactList.Add businesscontact
    Next
End Property
```

---

### Business contact Class - For the moment it only has one property

```
Private pBusinessContactName As String

Public Property Get Name() As String
    Name = pBusinessContactName
End Property

Public Property Let Name(ByVal sName As String)
    pBusinessContactName = sName
End Property
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are a few things that don't do what you expect in your code. I have cleaned it a bit and this new version should be closer to what you want. Let me know if the changes are not self-explanatory.

Main procedure:

```
Sub test()

    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long

    'code to populate some objects
    Dim clocklist As Collection
    Dim clock As classClocks
    Dim businessContactList As Collection
    Dim businessContact As classBusinessContact

    Set clocklist = New Collection

    For i = 1 To 3
        Set businessContactList = New Collection
        Set clock = New classClocks
        clock.LawyerName = "lawyer " & i
        For j = 1 To 3
            Set businessContact = New classBusinessContact
            businessContact.Name = "Business Contact " & j
            businessContactList.Add businessContact
        Next j
        Set clock.BusinessContactAdd = businessContactList
        clocklist.Add clock
    Next i

    Set businessContactList = Nothing

    'write the data backout again
    For Each clock In clocklist
        Debug.Print clock.LawyerName
        Set businessContactList = clock.BusinessContacts
        For Each businessContact In businessContactList
            Debug.Print businessContact.Name
        Next

    Next

End Sub
```

classClocks:

```
Private pLawyerName As String
Private pBusinessContactList As Collection

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
  Set pBusinessContactList = New Collection
End Sub

Public Property Get LawyerName() As String
    LawyerName = pLawyerName
End Property

Public Property Let LawyerName(ByVal sLawyerName As String)
    pLawyerName = sLawyerName
End Property

Public Property Get BusinessContacts() As Collection
    Set BusinessContacts = pBusinessContactList
End Property

Public Property Set BusinessContactAdd(contactCollection As Collection)

    For Each contactName In contactCollection
        pBusinessContactList.Add contactName
    Next

End Property
```

Comment: Thanks Assylias that works perfectly. I was trying to assemble the collection in the class. You did it outside and passed it in.

Answer (score 6):

I tend to make everything a class and chain the class calls together to access them.  It's not a better way than the one that assylias posted, just different.  And you may prefer it.

CClocks (collection class that's the parent of the CClock instances)

```
Private mcolClocks As Collection

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set mcolClocks = New Collection
End Sub

Private Sub Class_Terminate()
    Set mcolClocks = Nothing
End Sub

Public Property Get NewEnum() As IUnknown
    Set NewEnum = mcolClocks.[_NewEnum]
End Property

Public Sub Add(clsClock As CClock)
    If clsClock.ClockID = 0 Then
        clsClock.ClockID = Me.Count + 1
    End If

    Set clsClock.Parent = Me
    mcolClocks.Add clsClock, CStr(clsClock.ClockID)
End Sub

Public Property Get clock(vItem As Variant) As CClock
    Set clock = mcolClocks.Item(vItem)
End Property

Public Property Get Count() As Long
    Count = mcolClocks.Count
End Property
```

CClock class

```
Private mlClockID As Long
Private msLawyer As String
Private mlParentPtr As Long
Private mclsContacts As CContacts
Private Declare Sub CopyMemory Lib "kernel32" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" _
    (dest As Any, Source As Any, ByVal bytes As Long)


Public Property Set Contacts(ByVal clsContacts As CContacts): Set mclsContacts = clsContacts: End Property
Public Property Get Contacts() As CContacts: Set Contacts = mclsContacts: End Property
Public Property Let ClockID(ByVal lClockID As Long): mlClockID = lClockID: End Property
Public Property Get ClockID() As Long: ClockID = mlClockID: End Property
Public Property Let Lawyer(ByVal sLawyer As String): msLawyer = sLawyer: End Property
Public Property Get Lawyer() As String: Lawyer = msLawyer: End Property
Public Property Get Parent() As CClocks: Set Parent = ObjFromPtr(mlParentPtr): End Property
Public Property Set Parent(obj As CClocks): mlParentPtr = ObjPtr(obj): End Property

Private Function ObjFromPtr(ByVal pObj As Long) As Object
    Dim obj As Object
    CopyMemory obj, pObj, 4
    Set ObjFromPtr = obj
    ' manually destroy the temporary object variable
    ' (if you omit this step you'll get a GPF!)
    CopyMemory obj, 0&, 4
End Function

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set mclsContacts = New CContacts
End Sub

Private Sub Class_Terminate()
    Set mclsContacts = Nothing
End Sub
```

CContacts (parent class to CContact and a child to each CClock class)

```
Private mcolContacts As Collection

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set mcolContacts = New Collection
End Sub

Private Sub Class_Terminate()
    Set mcolContacts = Nothing
End Sub

Public Property Get NewEnum() As IUnknown
    Set NewEnum = mcolContacts.[_NewEnum]
End Property

Public Sub Add(clsContact As CContact)
    If clsContact.ContactID = 0 Then
        clsContact.ContactID = Me.Count + 1
    End If

    Set clsContact.Parent = Me
    mcolContacts.Add clsContact, CStr(clsContact.ContactID)
End Sub

Public Property Get Contact(vItem As Variant) As CContact
    Set Contact = mcolContacts.Item(vItem)
End Property

Public Property Get Count() As Long
    Count = mcolContacts.Count
End Property
```

CContact

```
Private mlContactID As Long
Private msContactName As String
Private mlParentPtr As Long
Private Declare Sub CopyMemory Lib "kernel32" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" _
    (dest As Any, Source As Any, ByVal bytes As Long)


Public Property Let ContactID(ByVal lContactID As Long): mlContactID = lContactID: End Property
Public Property Get ContactID() As Long: ContactID = mlContactID: End Property
Public Property Let ContactName(ByVal sContactName As String): msContactName = sContactName: End Property
Public Property Get ContactName() As String: ContactName = msContactName: End Property
Public Property Get Parent() As CContacts: Set Parent = ObjFromPtr(mlParentPtr): End Property
Public Property Set Parent(obj As CContacts): mlParentPtr = ObjPtr(obj): End Property

Private Function ObjFromPtr(ByVal pObj As Long) As Object
    Dim obj As Object
    CopyMemory obj, pObj, 4
    Set ObjFromPtr = obj
    ' manually destroy the temporary object variable
    ' (if you omit this step you'll get a GPF!)
    CopyMemory obj, 0&, 4
End Function
```

And the test procedure

```
Sub test()

    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim clsClocks As CClocks
    Dim clsClock As CClock
    Dim clsContact As CContact

    Set clsClocks = New CClocks

    For i = 1 To 3
        Set clsClock = New CClock
        clsClock.Lawyer = "lawyer " & i
        For j = 1 To 3
            Set clsContact = New CContact
            clsContact.ContactName = "Business Contact " & i & "-" & j
            clsClock.Contacts.Add clsContact
        Next j
        clsClocks.Add clsClock
    Next i

    'write the data backout again
    For Each clsClock In clsClocks
        Debug.Print clsClock.Lawyer
        For Each clsContact In clsClock.Contacts
            Debug.Print , clsContact.ContactName
        Next clsContact
    Next clsClock

End Sub
```

Instead of having Contacts as an integral part of CClock, I make it its own class/collection class.  Then I can access like

```
clsClock.Contacts.Item(1).ContactName
```

And I can use CContacts somewhere else in my code if it comes up.

You can ignore the NewEnum and CopyMemory stuff or read about it here http://www.dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2010/07/04/custom-collection-class/ and here http://www.dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2007/12/28/terminating-dependent-classes/#comment-29661  Those two parts are so I can have a Parent property without worrying about garbage collection (CopyMemory and ObjPtr) and so I can For.Each through the class (NewEnum).

Comment: Thanks Dick, this is a different way of looking at it, i found it a little tougher to follow, but once i got my head around the flow, it made a lot of sense.

Answer (score 3):

I haven't done VBA for a while, but I noticed this line:

```
Public Property Set BusinessContactAdd(ByRef strName() As Collection)
```

I *think* putting parentheses on a parameter name indicates that it's an array, which yours is not:  it's a single instance of a collection.