# Trying to set up a custom object model using example, not working

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to set up a custom object model using an example I found in an answered question here on stackoverflow.

[VBA Classes - How to have a class hold additional classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9686140/excel-vba-classes-how-to-have-a-class-hold-additional-classes/9686536#9686536)

Here is the code I have created based on the answer.

Standard Module

```
Sub test()

Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long

'code to populate some objects
Dim AssemList As Collection
Dim Assem As cAssem
Dim SubAssemList As Collection
Dim SubAssem As cSubAssem

Set AssemList = New Collection

For i = 1 To 3
    Set SubAssemList = New Collection
    Set Assem = New cAssem
    Assem.Description = "Assem " & i
    For j = 1 To 3
        Set SubAssem = New cSubAssem
        SubAssem.Name = "SubAssem" & j
        SubAssemList.Add SubAssem
    Next j
    Set Assem.SubAssemAdd = SubAssemList '<------ Object variable or With Block not Set
    AssemList.Add Assem
    Next i

Set SubAssemList = Nothing

'write the data backout again
For Each clock In AssemList
    Debug.Print Assem.Description
    Set SubAssemList = Assem.SubAssems
    For Each SubAssem In SubAssemList
        Debug.Print SubAssem.Name
    Next

Next

End Sub
```

cAssem Class

```
Private pDescription As String
Private pSubAssemList As Collection

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set pSubAssems = New Collection
End Sub

Public Property Get Description() As String
    Description = pDescription
End Property

Public Property Let Description(ByVal sDescription As String)
    pDescription = sDescription
End Property

Public Property Get SubAssems() As Collection
    Set SubAssems = pSubAssemList
End Property

Public Property Set SubAssemAdd(AssemCollection As Collection)

    For Each AssemName In AssemCollection
        pSubAssemList.Add AssemName ' <------- This is the line that is triggering the error
    Next

End Property
```

cSubAssem Class

```
Private pSubAssemName As String

Public Property Get Name() As String
    Name = pSubAssemName
End Property
Public Property Let Name(ByVal sName As String)
    pSubAssemName = sName
End Property
```

I have not changed anything in the code except class names and variable names and from  my limited point of view I cannot understand the cause of the error.

I am just starting to really dig into objects and Class Modules in VBA so I appreciate any knowledge this community could pass my way.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You have a typo in your sub class initializer:

```
Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set pSubAssems = New Collection
End Sub
```

should read:

```
Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set pSubAssemList = New Collection
End Sub
```