# Is it possible to access a parent property from a child that is in a collection?

Tags: excel, vba, oop, ms-access, ms-word

I've researched as much as I can and never found a definitive answer on this for VBA.

This older StackOverflow post has almost everything, but not quite. [VBA Classes - How to have a class hold additional classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9686140/excel-vba-classes-how-to-have-a-class-hold-additional-classes)

Bottom line - I have a class CClock, which is parent to a Collection of CContacts, which is parent to a CContact.

Is there any way to get at a property of the CClock class from a CContact.  So something like `Debug.Print , clsContact.Parent.Parent.Lawyer` in the code below?

I've tried setting the parents as I thought they should be but get the below error almost immediately at `Set clsClock = New CClock`.  When I follow the code it goes to class terminate event in the Contacts collection, which I can't figure out. (Although that is probably why the error below comes up.)

**`91 - Object Variable or With Variable not set`**

The various classes and a quick test rig are below (all based on Dick Kusleika's post in the link.)  Thanks.

(Edit- added the test routine, whooopsy)

```
Sub test()

    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim clsClocks As CClocks
    Dim clsClock As CClock
    Dim clsContact As CContact

    Set clsClocks = New CClocks

    For i = 1 To 3
        Set clsClock = New CClock
        clsClock.Lawyer = "lawyer " & i
        For j = 1 To 3
            Set clsContact = New CContact
            clsContact.ContactName = "Business Contact " & i & "-" & j
            clsClock.Contacts.Add clsContact
        Next j
        clsClocks.Add clsClock
    Next i

    For i = 1 To 2
        Set clsContact = New CContact
        clsContact.ContactName = "Business Contact 66" & "-" & i
        clsClocks(2).Contacts.Add clsContact
    Next i

    'write the data backout again
    For Each clsClock In clsClocks
        Debug.Print clsClock.Lawyer
        For Each clsContact In clsClock.Contacts
            Debug.Print , clsContact.ContactName
            Debug.Print , clsContact.Parent.Parent.Lawyer

        Next clsContact
    Next clsClock


End Sub
```

**Clas CClocks**

```
'CClocks
Option Explicit
Private mcolClocks As Collection
Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set mcolClocks = New Collection
End Sub
Private Sub Class_Terminate()
    Set mcolClocks = Nothing
End Sub
Public Property Get NewEnum() As IUnknown
    Set NewEnum = mcolClocks.[_NewEnum]
End Property
Public Sub Add(clsClock As CClock)
    If clsClock.ClockID = 0 Then
        clsClock.ClockID = Me.Count + 1
    End If

    Set clsClock.Parent = Me
    mcolClocks.Add clsClock, CStr(clsClock.ClockID)
End Sub
Public Property Get Clock(vItem As Variant) As CClock
    Set Clock = mcolClocks.Item(vItem)
End Property
Public Property Get Count() As Long
    Count = mcolClocks.Count
End Property
Public Sub Remove(vItem As Variant)
        clsClock.Remove vItem
End Sub
Public Sub Clear()
        Set clsClock = New Collection
End Sub
```

**Class CClock**

```
'CClock
Private mlClockID As Long
Private msLawyer As String
Private mlParentPtr As Long
Private mclsContacts As CContacts
Private Declare Sub CopyMemory Lib "kernel32" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" _
    (dest As Any, Source As Any, ByVal bytes As Long)
Public Property Set Contacts(ByVal clsContacts As CContacts): Set mclsContacts = clsContacts: End Property
Public Property Get Contacts() As CContacts: Set Contacts = mclsContacts: End Property
Public Property Let ClockID(ByVal lClockID As Long): mlClockID = lClockID: End Property
Public Property Get ClockID() As Long: ClockID = mlClockID: End Property
Public Property Let Lawyer(ByVal sLawyer As String): msLawyer = sLawyer: End Property
Public Property Get Lawyer() As String: Lawyer = msLawyer: End Property
Public Property Get Parent() As CClocks: Set Parent = ObjFromPtr(mlParentPtr): End Property
Public Property Set Parent(obj As CClocks): mlParentPtr = ObjPtr(obj): End Property
Private Function ObjFromPtr(ByVal pObj As Long) As Object
    Dim obj As Object
    CopyMemory obj, pObj, 4
    Set ObjFromPtr = obj
    ' manually destroy the temporary object variable
    ' (if you omit this step you'll get a GPF!)
    CopyMemory obj, 0&, 4
End Function
Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set mclsContacts = New CContacts
    Set Me.Contacts.Parent = Me
End Sub
Private Sub Class_Terminate()
    Set mclsContacts = Nothing
End Sub
'CContacts
Option Explicit
Private mcolContacts As Collection
Private mlParentPtr As Long
Private Declare Sub CopyMemory Lib "kernel32" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" _
    (dest As Any, Source As Any, ByVal bytes As Long)
Public Property Get Parent() As CClock: Set Parent = ObjFromPtr(mlParentPtr): End Property
Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set mcolContacts = New Collection
End Sub
Private Sub Class_Terminate()
    Set mcolContacts = Nothing
End Sub
Public Property Get NewEnum() As IUnknown
    Set NewEnum = mcolContacts.[_NewEnum]
End Property
Public Sub Add(clsContact As CContact)
    If clsContact.ContactID = 0 Then
        clsContact.ContactID = Me.Count + 1
    End If
    Set clsContact.Parent = Me
    mcolContacts.Add clsContact, CStr(clsContact.ContactID)
End Sub
Public Property Get Clock(vItem As Variant) As CContact
    Set Clock = mcolContacts.Item(vItem)
End Property
Public Property Get Count() As Long
    Count = mcolContacts.Count
End Property
Public Sub Remove(vItem As Variant)
        clsContact.Remove vItem
End Sub
Public Sub Clear()
        Set clsContact = New Colletion
End Sub
Private Function ObjFromPtr(ByVal pObj As Long) As Object
    Dim obj As Object
    CopyMemory obj, pObj, 4
    Set ObjFromPtr = obj
    ' manually destroy the temporary object variable
    ' (if you omit this step you'll get a GPF!)
    CopyMemory obj, 0&, 4
End Function
```

**Class CContact**

```
'CContact
Private mlContactID As Long
Private msContactName As String
Private mlParentPtr As Long
Private Declare Sub CopyMemory Lib "kernel32" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" _
    (dest As Any, Source As Any, ByVal bytes As Long)

Public Property Let ContactID(ByVal lContactID As Long): mlContactID = lContactID: End Property
Public Property Get ContactID() As Long: ContactID = mlContactID: End Property
Public Property Let ContactName(ByVal sContactName As String): msContactName = sContactName: End Property
Public Property Get ContactName() As String: ContactName = msContactName: End Property
Public Property Get Parent() As CContacts: Set Parent = ObjFromPtr(mlParentPtr): End Property
Public Property Set Parent(obj As CContacts): mlParentPtr = ObjPtr(obj): End Property
Private Function ObjFromPtr(ByVal pObj As Long) As Object
    Dim obj As Object
    CopyMemory obj, pObj, 4
    Set ObjFromPtr = obj
    ' manually destroy the temporary object variable
    ' (if you omit this step you'll get a GPF!)
    CopyMemory obj, 0&, 4
End Function
```

Comment: Also see this for more information about that [Win32 CopyMemory API call](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa140182(v=office.10).aspx)

Comment: There's quite a lot wrong with that code as posted but to begin with your CContacts class is missing a Parent property Set procedure.

Comment: Sorry, I was switching laptops and Flash Drives while travelling.  Might have posted the module without the parent prop I was trying to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you figure out how to access the kernel memory to do this, let me know. Take a look at the source code of [vbWatchDog](http://www.everythingaccess.com/vbwatchdog.htm) for some hints. I have been studying it to try to gain access to the call stack. I haven't figured it out yet.

I'll show you how to fake it though. I'm going to simplify this a bit. You'll need to apply the principle to your own code. The trick is kind of ugly. It requires that we call an `Initialize` routine each time we create a new child object

**The Parent Class:**

```
'Class Parent
Option Explicit

Private mName as String
Public Property Get Name() as String
    Name = mName()
End Property

Public Property Let Name(value As String)
    mName = value
End Property
```

**The Child class**

```
'Class Child
Option Explicit

Private mParent as Parent    

Public Property Get Parent() as Parent
    Set Parent = mParent
End Property

Public Property Let Name(Obj as Parent)
    Set mParent = Obj
End Property

Public Sub Initialize(Obj as Parent)
    Set Me.Parent = Obj
End Sub
```

**Creating a Child object:**

```
Sub CreateChild()
    Dim parentObject As New Parent
    ' create child object with parent property
    Dim childObject As New Child
    childObject.Initialize(parentObject)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks ck, finally got a chance to do a quick run through and I'm getting a (Object doesn't support prop or method" when it hits the .init line.)  Haven't had a chance to play around at all with it, but I did notice you didn't have any collections in here, which I think is part of my issue.  Can a collection be a child and also a parent, and how do I travsere that?  Or so I think.

Comment: What .Init() line? The code I posted uses .Initialize?

Comment: Yes. A collection can be both a parent and a child. You can actually see an [example I wrote with that kind of implementation](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/52364/extending-the-vba-extensibility-library). In that example, vbeCodeModule is parent to vbeProcedures, which is a collection of vbeProcedure objects.

Comment: Thanks.  I adapted what you did there to my code and voila!

Comment: Excellent news! Please accept/up vote if you found my answer useful.

Comment: FYI - in your vbeProcedure I think the GetErrorSource() CurrentProject variable is not defined.  Thanks again for the help.