# VBA pass parent class to child class

Tags: vba, class, subclass

I found a great post on SO that seems to be exactly what I want: [Is it possible to access a parent property from a child that is in a collection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23976780/is-it-possible-to-access-a-parent-property-from-a-child-that-is-in-a-collection) However my adaptation of it is giving me `Object doesn't support this property or method.`

My code which now works thanks to Mat's Mug and Tomalak:

***Parent Class - clsComputer***

```
Option Explicit
Private pCD As clsCD

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' CD property
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Public Property Get CD() As clsCD
    If pCD Is Nothing Then
        Set pCD = New clsCD
        'Per Mat's Mug post, drop the parenthesis
        pCD.Initialze Me
    End If
    Set CD = pCD
End Property
Public Property Set CD(value As clsCD)
    pCD = value
End Property
```

***Child class - clsCD***

```
Option Explicit

Private pParent As clsComputer

'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Status property - READ ONLY
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Public Property Get Status(Optional strHost As String) As String
    Dim strResult As String

    If strHost = "" Then strHost = Me.Parent.HostName

    strResult = RunCMD("cmd /c ""winrs -r:" & strHost & _
        " reg query hklm\system\currentcontrolset\services\cdrom /v start""")
    If InStr(1, strResult, "0x4", vbTextCompare) Then
        Status = "Disabled"
    Else
        Status = "Enabled"
    End If
End Property

'''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Parent property
'''''''''''''''''''''''''
Public Property Get Parent() As clsComputer
    Set Parent = pParent
End Property

'Because as Tomalak points out, you use Set with Objects.
Public Property Set Parent(Obj As clsComputer)
    Set pParent = Obj
End Property

'''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Initialize Method
'''''''''''''''''''''''''
Public Sub Initialize(Obj As clsComputer)
    Set Me.Parent = Obj
End Sub
```

***Code Module - Module1***

```
Sub test()
    Dim oPC As clsComputer
    Set oPC = New clsComputer
    Debug.Print "CD Status: " & oPC.CD.Status
End Sub
```

If I test Me, it is an object (eg, `If IsObject(Me) Then Stop` evaluates true), and Intellisense shows all the properties and methods in clsComputer when I type `Me.` The Locals windows shows Me as a clsComputer object. Everything I know to check says Me is a clsComputer object, so what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Classic.

> ```
> pCD.Initialize (Me) 'Error occurs on this line when using F8
> ```

Drop the parentheses.

```
pCD.Initialize Me
```

Done.

Parentheses around a parameter **force it to be *evaluated* and passed ByVal** (regardless of what the procedure's signature says) - and since you probably haven't defined a default property for `clsComputer` then the evaluation blows up and the runtime doesn't even get to the `Initialize` method.

That said, there's nothing wrong with passing object reference by value. In fact, that's what C# and VB.NET do by default - consider passing *any* parameter `ByVal`.

Comment: Aha! Between this and @tomalak, that fixes it! I will update my post.

Comment: Awesome. Finally I know the last bit about want parens do. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

```
Public Property Set Parent(ByRef Obj As clsComputer)
    Set pParent = Obj
End Property
```

Comment: No dice. It still errors out. ByRef is default for objects, so changing from Let to Set did not correct the issue.

Comment: But you can't even `Let` an object reference, AFAIK. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Not wrong, absolutely correct. Except I'd pass the object reference by value, not by reference. @Tim `Property Let` is for value types. Use `Property Set` for objects.

Comment: Yeah, you are correct @Tomalak. You can't `Let` objects. Sadly, that still fails. If I remark `pCD.Initialize (Me)` and just `Set pCD.Parent = Me`, the code works fine.

Comment: @Tim see my answer

Answer (score 0):

I'm not by my PC so just coding blind

Try this for your **clsComputer** class

```
Option Explicit
Private pCD As clsCD

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' CD property
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''' 
Public Property Get CD() As clsCD
    Set CD = pCD
End Property

Public Property Set CD(value As clsCD)
    pCD = value
End Property

Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set pCD = New clsCD
    pCD.Initialize(Me)
End Property
```