# Getting an error when using parent property with arrays in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, parent-child

I'm getting a run-time error 91 in VBA (object variable or With block not set).

I'm trying to access a property of a parent class that I constructed but I'm getting the error 91. I can access the property without using the Parent property but when I use the parent property I'm getting an error.

I have 4 classes (Employees, Employee, Engineers, and Engineer). Employees and Engineers hold a collection of Employee and Engineer respectively (I'm not using the collection object here though. I'm just using a simple array).

My Employee class.

```
Option Explicit
Private objEngineers As Engineers
Private objEngineer As Engineer
Private varCode As Variant

Private Sub Class_Initialize()

    Set objEngineer = New Engineer

    Set objEngineer.Parent = Me

End Sub
Public Property Get Engineers() As Engineers

    Set Engineers = objEngineers

End Property
Public Property Set Engineers(objmEngineers As Engineers)

    Set objEngineers = objmEngineers

End Property
Public Property Get Code() As Variant

    Code = varCode

End Property
Public Property Let Code(varmCode As Variant)

    varCode = varmCode

End Property
```

Employees class

```
Option Explicit
Private objEmployee() As Employee
Sub Add()

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim objEngineers As Engineers

    Set objEngineers = New Engineers

    objEngineers.Add

    ReDim objEmployee(1 To 3)

    For i = 1 To 3
        Set objEmployee(i) = New Employee
        objEmployee(i).Code = "Employee " & i
        Set objEmployee(i).Engineers = objEngineers
    Next

End Sub
Property Get Item(i As Integer) As Employee

    Set Item = objEmployee(i)

End Property
```

Engineer Class

```
    Option Explicit
Private objEmployee As Employee
Private varID As Variant
Property Get Parent() As Employee

    Set Parent = objEmployee

End Property
Property Set Parent(objmEmployee As Employee)

    Set objEmployee = objmEmployee

End Property
Public Property Get ID() As Variant

    ID = varID

End Property
Public Property Let ID(varmID As Variant)

    varID = varmID

End Property
```

Engineers class

```
    Option Explicit
Private objEngineer() As Engineer
Private objEmployee As Employee
Sub Add()

    Dim i As Integer
    ReDim objEngineer(1 To 3)

    For i = 1 To 3
        Set objEngineer(i) = New Engineer
        objEngineer(i).ID = "Engineer " & i
    Next

End Sub
Property Get Item(i As Integer) As Engineer

    Set Item = objEngineer(i)

End Property
```

Finally my test module

```
    Option Explicit
Sub Main()

    Dim objEmployees As Employees
    Dim i As Integer

    Set objEmployees = New Employees

    objEmployees.Add

    For i = 1 To 3
        Debug.Print objEmployees.Item(i).Engineers.Item(i).ID
        Debug.Print objEmployees.Item(i).Code
        Debug.Print objEmployees.Item(i).Engineers.Item(i).Parent.Code
    Next

End Sub
```

I can make the first line in the loop to work "Engineer 1". Also, the second line that gives "Employee 1" works but the 3rd line that should give me the same result as the second line I get the error. I can't access the properties of Employee when I use the Parent property from Engineer.

I know I'm missing something obvious that I just can't find it.

Comment: [See this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9688292/445425) that demonstrates how to create a parent property in VBA.

Comment: Chris, the answer that you suggested from the other thread doesn't compile. In the other post I'm getting error at the line with comment 'write the data backout again'. I'm open to try the suggestion but I can't make it work it.

Comment: The _technique_ does work, I've used it in one of my projects.  Haven't actually tried the example Dick posted though. No time right now, but I'll try and post a working sample latter.

Answer (score 1):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9688292/445425) by [Dick Kusleika](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4280/dick-kusleika)

Distilled down to just enough to demonstrate a parent property

Class Module `ParentClass`

```
Option Explicit

Private pName As String
Private pChild As ChildClass


Public Property Let Name(NewName As String)
    pName = NewName
End Property
Public Property Get Name() As String
    Name = pName
End Property

Public Property Get Child() As ChildClass
    Set Child = pChild
End Property

Public Sub Add(NewName As String)
    Set pChild = New ChildClass
    pChild.Name = NewName
    Set pChild.Parent = Me
End Sub
```

Class Module `ChildClass`

```
Option Explicit

Private Declare Sub CopyMemory Lib "kernel32" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" _
    (dest As Any, Source As Any, ByVal bytes As Long)

Private pName As String
Private pParentPtr As Long

Public Property Let Name(NewName As String)
    pName = NewName
End Property
Public Property Get Name() As String
    Name = pName
End Property

Public Property Get Parent() As ParentClass
    Set Parent = ObjFromPtr(pParentPtr)
End Property
Friend Property Set Parent(Obj As ParentClass)
    pParentPtr = ObjPtr(Obj)
End Property



Private Function ObjFromPtr(ByVal pObj As Long) As Object
    Dim Obj As Object
    CopyMemory Obj, pObj, 4
    Set ObjFromPtr = Obj
    ' manually destroy the temporary object variable
    ' (if you omit this step you'll get a GPF!)
    CopyMemory Obj, 0&, 4
End Function
```

Standard Module for demonstration purposes

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim EgParent As ParentClass
    Dim EgChild As ChildClass

    Set EgParent = New ParentClass
    EgParent.Name = "I am the Parent"
    EgParent.Add "I am the Child"

    Set EgChild = EgParent.Child


    Debug.Print EgParent.Name
    Debug.Print EgChild.Name
    Debug.Print EgChild.Parent.Name

End Sub
```